# How To Pass Multiple Variables In One value in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 requested variables in php code, use blow,

```
$boddate=$_REQUEST['boddate'];
$bodmonth=$_REQUEST['bodmonth'];
$bodyear=$_REQUEST['bodyear'];
```

I want to get that 3 variables on one value. ($dateofbirth=) How to coding in php for send mysql database.

And I have imported question is that value , first and third characters want displayed and other  characters removed using "substr" php commend , I want check for first in removed character,
Eg- I have value "America"
I want get using substr commend "A" and "E" characters,

```
    $cu = "America";
    $country1= substr($cu, 0,1);
    $country2= substr($cu, 2,1);
```

I'm not sure how to all variables get in one and three characters,

Comment: -1 super trivial question that you could have easily found the answer too in any basic PHP tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) them using the `.`.

```
$birthdate = $boddate."-".$bodmonth."-".$bodyear; // D-M-Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $birthdate=$_REQUEST['bodyear'].'-'.$_REQUEST['bodmonth'].'-'.$_REQUEST['boddate'];
```